# Magento Paypal Report

Tags: magento, paypal, report

I'm trying run the Magento Paypal Settlement Report under Reports > Sales, but each time I attempt to run the report I get the message "Nothing to fetch because of an empty configuration"

I've looked under the System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods, but don't see any options to configure information for the report.

Can someone point me to where the relevant information must be configured to run this report.

Thank you,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your SFTP credentials under System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Paypal Payment Solutions (see Screenshot below).

You have to be signed up for the SFTP Server. Have a look at http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/servicemanagement_help/rep_setupftp.htm#accessing for more information.

Your cron job should also be configured correctly to fetch the data from PayPal.

[image]